# How do you get pgAdmin to connect to postgress

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Installed postgres on Debian 10 using

```
# apt install postgres postgres-contrib
```

Can connect to it after setting the password for the `postgres user`

```
# passwd postgres
...
# su postgres
$ cd
$ pwd /var/lib/postgresql
$ psql
psql (11.17 (Debian 11.17-0+deb10u1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \conninfo
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
postgres=#
```

I've installed pgAdmin on Windows and SSH into Debian with port forwarding `-L 5432:localhost:5432` but pgAdmin complains that the password (that I've just set) is incorrect.

[image]

I've tried

```
postgres=# ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'password'
```

but it doesn't make any difference.

**Update**

This is suspicious; it doesn't even a password?

```
# psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

**Update 2**

Tried to create a second user

```
# CREATE ROLE sa WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'password'
```

For some reason the `psql` command now asks for a password, but it does not accept the (correct) password

```
# psql -U sa
Password for user sa:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "sa"
```

I notice that `\du` lists only one user, `postgres` and not also the second user that I thought I'd created.

This is such shit.

Comment: have you tried your user name and passowrd or create a user and password, as you already have admin rights

Comment: The username is `postgres` -- as shown in the screenshot. And the password I entered in pgAdmin matches the one I set with `passwd postgres` and `ALTER USER postgres...`.

Comment: pgadmin asks for its own password when you install it

Comment: Yes, I've set the password. (I thought I'd made that clear.) My problem is that pgAdmin can't use the username and password to connect to postgres.

Comment: instaed of the ip use localhost, so it should use sockets and not tcp/IP

Comment: Look in the database servers log file for more details on the login failures.

Answer (score 0):

You are running PostgreSQL over a Unix socket. pgAdmin needs a TCP/IP connection. You can fix this by making the necessary changes to `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf`. Note that PostgreSQL on Unix runs over a socket by default so you have to explicitly indicate that you want to use a TCP/IP connection. Also, make sure to restart the server after making any changes